# Parse 1.3 throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS start when ByteCode stripping is on in Unity 4.5.3f

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

Crash in xcode:

[image: Stack trace of crash]

With no luck, I've tried solving this with a link.xml which contains:

```
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="Parse.Unity">
    <namespace fullname="Parse" preserve="all"/>
    <namespace fullname="Parse.Internal" preserve="all"/>
    <namespace fullname="Parse.PlatformHooks" preserve="all"/>
    <namespace fullname="System" preserve="all"/>
    <namespace fullname="System.Threading" preserve="all"/>
    <namespace fullname="System.Threading.Tasks" preserve="all"/>
    <namespace fullname="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" preserve="all"/>
    <namespace fullname="System.Runtime.ExceptionServices" preserve="all"/>
  </assembly>
</linker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Parse SDK 1.3.3 is now released https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads. Stripping works for Android builds and I have not been able to test on iOS yet, but the release notes mention that stripping is fixed.

This should be fixed in the next release after 1.3.2: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1535229776715182

I've reproduced in 1.3.0 and 1.3.1